# Using AJAX to load page into a div at a specific anchor

Tags: javascript, ajax, anchor

I've seen a few questions on here related to this, but I'm not seeing the exact situation I'm talking about so I figured I'd ask.

I have a page with two divs. A sidenav div (`sidediv`) and a main body (`maindiv`) div.

What I want:
To click a link in the side nav to load a page in the main div. At the moment, anyway, it's always the same page, but it's a huge page with several anchors. The items in the side link to varied anchors.

What I'm doing:
My sidenav links look like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="loadPage('mypage.html#ds'); return false;">Desired Section</a>
```

and the JS:

```
function loadPage(url){
    var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (this.readyState!==4) return;
        if (this.status!==200) return; 
        document.getElementById('maindiv').innerHTML= this.responseText;
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

What happens:
It loads mypage.html just fine, but refuses to go to the anchor.

How do I make that happen (sans jQuery, BTW, I currently am not using it on site and don't feel like loading it in for one thing)

Thanks.

Comment: The anchor mechanism is done by the browser from the url. Since you're not loading the html into the browser as a page but instead stuffing into a div element, it will never "scroll" to the anchor.

Comment: Ok. Is there another way I can accomplish this effect?

Comment: If the containing div is relative then you can use the offsetTop prop

Comment: How canI possibly know how much to offset it by, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was interesting so I took a shot at it for you. Here is what I came up with. It uses `scrollIntoView`. Also keep in mind that I simulated the ajax call so my `loadPage` function does some stuff differently than you will.

```js
var pages = {
    'mypage.html': '<div id="ts" class="page">my stuff</div><div id="ds" class="page">my more stuff</div><div id="eds" class="page">my even more stuff</div>',
    'yourpage.html': '<div id="ts" class="page">your stuff</div><div id="ds" class="page">your more stuff</div><div id="eds" class="page">your even more stuff</div>'
};

function loadPage(url) {
    var set = url.split('#'),
        page = set[0],
        id = set[1];

    // simulate xhr request
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('maindiv').innerHTML = pages[page];
        document.getElementById(id).scrollIntoView();
    }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.page {
  height: 400px;
}

.menu {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
}

#maindiv {
  width: 50px;
  float: right;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('mypage.html#ds'); return false;">My Page #ds</a><br />
    <a href="#" onclick="loadPage('yourpage.html#eds'); return false;">Your Page #eds</a>
</div>

<div id="maindiv">
</div>
```

Comment: I was literally just working with scrollIntoView, but hadn't figured it out yet. Thanks so much for this, I'll try it out right now!

Comment: Hrm. While I see it working in your example, it doesn't work with mine. I had to change a bit to make it fit my code, perhaps I messed something up. Do you see what I may have done? (I'm now only sending in the anchor name, since the page is always the same. code in next comment. It's saying that the document.getElementById(hash) is null

Comment: function loadPage(hash){
        var url = "helpdoc.html";
        var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
            if (this.readyState!==4) return;
            if (this.status!==200) return; 
            document.getElementById('maindiv').innerHTML= this.responseText;
            document.getElementById(hash).scrollIntoView();
        };
        xhr.send();
    }

Comment: Got it! I had to move that last line after the xhr.send() since it didn't exist yet. My CSS is off, but I can deal with that. The scrolling works!

Comment: Glad I could help.